# Use of "another" and "different" in context

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Tell me please which one of the following sentences is correct.

> When I put **another** SIM card in my tablet of **another** mobile internet provider, it works.
>
> When I put a **different** SIM card in my tablet of a **different** mobile internet provider, it works.

I guess these two sentences might be correct, if so, then what is the difference then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both words can be used in this context but both your sentences are ambiguous and a bit awkward, because the repetition (of "another" or "different") are implying multiple kinds of differences between SIM cards and providers, when I think (?) you mean just one. If so, I would say:

> When I put a SIM card from a [another/different] mobile internet provider into my tablet, it works.

You don't need to (and shouldn't) repeat the word ("different") unless you mean it's not only a different provider but *also* some different *kind* of SIM card.